# Fastlane CI/CD container setup

Tags: fastlane

I am looking into how to use Fastlane in a custom CI/CD setup and first step is to use a Fastlane docker container. I found [this](https://github.com/fastlane/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) Dockerfile. Have you seen any CI/CD setup(examples) using Fastlane?

Note: I am planning on building ios on the new XCode Cloud so it will only be Android.